# How to publish packages with + sign in the version (Semver 2.0.0) to npm?

Tags: npm, semantic-versioning

I see semver 2.0.0 supports versions like 1.0.0-beta+1.1. Here are the valid versions according to semver 2.0.0:
https://semver.org/#is-there-a-suggested-regular-expression-regex-to-check-a-semver-string

But when i try to publish this package. I see the version getting published as just 1.0.0-beta. It is truncating anything after "+" sign. Am I missing anything?

Thanks,
KS

Comment: Also see this [issue #1479](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/1479), particularly [this comment](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/1479#issuecomment-652846253) by @isaacs - it states: _"The reason that npm drops build info from SemVer versions and ranges is that it's not relevant for the purpose of dependency resolution. (Ie, `1.0.0+foo` is "the same" as `1.0.0+bar` or just `1.0.0`, as far as SemVer is concerned.) Unlike build metadata, prerelease version identifiers are relevant. `1.0.0-foo` is not the same as `1.0.0-bar`, and both are meaningfully different from `1.0.0`."_

Comment: Ya they've definitely got it all wrong.  One best practice is to add the repo hash the package was build from, for provenance.  They should NEVER drop any data the publisher deems relevant.